# Fill a column based on certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1`:

```
Site    cells   national plan value
T13630  G13630B 225
T13631  G13631A 
T13631  U13631A 57
T13672  G13672A 310
T13802  G13802A 150
T13802  G13802B 151
T13802  U13802A 
T13880  G13880A 274
T13880  U13880B 
T33281  U33281A
```

I want dataframe `df2` such that I want to fill the blanks in "national plan value" column based on the some conditions.

The conditions are first consider the cell that has blank national plan value. if any other cell has same site name (the other cell can be above / below this cell) and if the last letter of the cell matches e.g. G13631A & U13631A, then copy the national plan value of U13631A to G13631A else write "no-cosector".

Hence my resultant dataframe `df2` should have something like this:

```
Site    cells   national plan value
T13630  G13630B 225
T13631  G13631A 57
T13631  U13631A 57
T13672  G13672A 310
T13802  G13802A 150
T13802  G13802B 151
T13802  U13802A 150
T13880  G13880A 274
T13880  U13880B no-cosector
T33281  U33281A no-cosector
```

Comment: can you help me how to attach the excel? i don't find any option here

Comment: @Sam I think Question has enough information to reproduce a problem. There's no need for extra file or data.

Comment: plz find the link for the excel :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lA8kEVBYZ8cxUqH7AmpHhz4JR6p2fZuJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar : I was asking for the file so that I do not have to create a sample file for trying out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new column that will be used to identify the rows that belong to the same class:

```
df1['ind'] = df1['Site'] + df1['cells'].str[-1]
```

Sort by that column. This way, all rows that belong to the same class are consecutive:

```
df1.sort_values(['ind', 'npv'], inplace=True)
```

Fill the rows that do not have duplicates in the same class:

```
df1.loc[~df1.duplicated(subset='ind') & df1['npv'].isnull(), 'npv'] = 'no-cosector'
```

Fill the rows that do have duplicates in the same class:

```
df1['npv'].ffill(inplace=True)
```

Remove the temporary column:

```
df1.drop('ind',axis=1)
```

Enjoy:

```
#     Site    cells          npv
#0  T13630  G13630B          225
#2  T13631  U13631A           57
#1  T13631  G13631A           57
#3  T13672  G13672A          310
#4  T13802  G13802A          150
#6  T13802  U13802A          150
#5  T13802  G13802B          151
#7  T13880  G13880A          274
#8  T13880  U13880B  no-cosector
#9  T33281  U33281A  no-cosector
```

Comment: but i have a issue with this... it fills the other columns wherever it is blank.. it should not fill other columns except "npv" column

Comment: See the modified answer.

Comment: link for raw-file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dfUhNx3MCjLrDHMnXMKjEyUb7Jmrz1No
link for output data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lA8kEVBYZ8cxUqH7AmpHhz4JR6p2fZuJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You can build a column with the last char of the cells col and then groupby Site and the last char column. Finally fill na accordingly.

```
df_new = (
     df1.assign(cells_last=df1.cells.str.slice(-1))
     .groupby(['Site','cells_last'])
     .apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
     .fillna('no-cosector')
     .reindex(columns=df1.columns)
     )

df_new
Out[104]: 
     Site    cells national_plan_value
0  T13630  G13630B                 225
1  T13631  G13631A                  57
2  T13631  U13631A                  57
3  T13672  G13672A                 310
4  T13802  G13802A                 150
5  T13802  G13802B                 151
6  T13802  U13802A                 150
7  T13880  G13880A                 274
8  T13880  U13880B         no-cosector
9  T33281  U33281A         no-cosector
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, create a new column:

```
df["cellsend"] = df["cells"].str.slice(1)
```

Step 2, use `sort_values` and `groupby` to fill na:

```
df.sort_values(["Site", "cellsend", "national plan value"]).groupby(["Site", "cellsend"]).ffill().drop(["cellsend"], axis=1).fillna("no-cosector")
```

Output:

```
    Site    cells       national plan value
0   T13630  G13630B     225
2   T13631  U13631A     57
1   T13631  G13631A     57
3   T13672  G13672A     310
4   T13802  G13802A     150
6   T13802  U13802A     150
5   T13802  G13802B     151
7   T13880  G13880A     274
8   T13880  U13880B     no-cosector
9   T33281  U33281A     no-cosector
```